# Identifying an IC with markings: 0270000 DCP1227 0601

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification, markings

I have a chip on one of my boards, and I cannot identify it. I tried differnet variations of search patterns but I cannot find it anywhere. The marking on the chip are in three rows as following: 
0270000
DCP1227
0601

It seems to be 12 pins total, in groups of three pins in each corner. 
[image: chip]

I am wondering if the reason I cannot find this chip is because the manufacturer was bought out or went out of business?

I suspect this to be a DC/DC converter from Burr-Brown (bought by TI back in 2000). But I could not find any information about the markings in any online document. I wonder if anyone has an old catalog with a table of product numbers and markings of BB?

Comment: I think an image of the component would help identify it.

Comment: Thanks, I just added a picture. Its from the side to make both the markings and the pinout from the side available.

Comment: BTW, I suspect it to be a Burr-Brown DC converter. But I could not find this exact part number in any datasheet.

Comment: It may also be an isolation amplifier - the wide pin spacing in the middle of the package would allow for high voltage between the input and output sections. An isolated DC-DC converter would also be possible.

Comment: What else is it connected to?

Comment: 3 caps , 2 resistors, pos AND gate, PCB trace antenna

Comment: I don't think that's a BB chip. They would have their logo on it. RF module, maybe.

Comment: What's the board it's on?

Comment: I would guess that this was made in week 6 of 2001, and you know I think I used one of these in a design back then.  I think it's an isolated DCDC made by somebody like Murata.  I may even have one in the loft.....Though back then, data was in books which I threw out years ago...doh!

Comment: If I am right, then 1227 means 12V to 27V, it's input range.

Comment: Murata search did not bring anything back. So did not a search for 1.2V to 2.7V. Anyone knows of an IC search engine one that you can search by lot, date, marking, etc?

Comment: Have you used a voltmeter to determine any voltage levels between any of the pins? (assuming you don't want to know the part number to replace it!)

Comment: I do want to know the part number to replace it :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be a custom IC made just for the company whose board it is on. I ran into this once without realizing it. I made an educated guess about the manufacturer, and even called them up for help. Their response was something along the lines of "This is a custom part for one of our customers. How do you have it?" I don't remember what I said in response, but I ended the conversation quickly.

If you are able to, remove the part from its pads. This will help you:

- Check if there are any markings on the bottom of the IC.
- Put it in a test environment to see if it does what you think it does. Be very careful with this though, as you will likely burn out the IC if you guess wrong.

Comment: In this world of surplus parts, that's very common. I've gotten that a couple of times with character displays. You just gotta find the closest generic part that manufacturer sells and assume most of the stuff is close enough in specs. AFAIK, even big companies like TI does custom parts.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that they have the $ power to request a special design IC. I just do not see them having enough income to request something like that - after all, changing a mask alone costs several $k's... 

I dont want to remove the part as it does not have "leg" pins. Its going to be hard to take off and put back.

Comment: Decent iron, flux and solderwick = easy peasy.

Comment: But I want to put it back in afterwards, and those are not "pins", but more like pads. Its going to be somewhat harder than the usual soldering work.

Comment: Although this answer is not giving me any special direct solution, it is the only one here, and I would feel if the points would just disappear. But Thank you for the effort and discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that is a 27MHz EPSON SG8002 oscillator equivalent

Comment: This is correct. It's an oscillator 27MHz. This answer should not be marked as negative.